# Load filtered OSM relations into Postgis with OSMOSIS

Tags: postgis, openstreetmap, osmosis

I am really hitting the wall trying to grips with merging filters in OSMOSIS.

I would like to load relations, their related nodes and ways.

If I use a tag filter like this:

```
--tf accept-relations route=train,bus --used-way --used-node
```

I get all the nodes associated with every way. This is not half bad but I would only like to load the nodes related to the route relations, ie. the bus stops and rail stations.

If I put the --used-node before --used-way then all nodes (buildings, poi, etc) are loaded, that is bad.

Loading NO nodes and just ways doesn't seem to be possible at all. :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need those nodes of the way to get the way geometry. OpenStreetmap does not store any vertex coordinates in the way table, only the reference to the node number.

Using osm2pgsql gives you the points you want, i.e. only nodes with additional tags.